# Is it possible to lose data on an external SSD drive despite using the "safe remove" feature?

Tags: windows-7, usb, ssd, external-hard-drive

I have an SSD disk in a third party USB 3.0 disk enclosure. The drive is NTFS formatted.

Lately, I've almost lost some of my data despite using the "safe remove" windows feature.

Here is what happened:

1. I've connected the drive to an usb slot.
2. Moved some big files to it.
3. After the progress bar disapeared, I "safely detached" the drive.
4. After it disappeared form system, I disconnected the drive.
5. Upon reconnection files were missing. Checkdisk was able to restore them.

I wonder, If it is an issue with the disk reporting write prematurely while holding data in cache.

Comment: Yes, SSD drives do die like all other hardware. However, does the size of free space on the disk indicate the data is there (just not visible)? Your AV may be removing it.

Comment: You have options to change the write cache of any disk, most of the externals can be changed too.  There is also possiblities here for having minor corruption from previous instances (of any kind). The previous minor issue rears its head when a chkdsk would have cleaned up the minor issue, before writing again to the drive.